# Disable an input field for x Days

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I submitted my form today i.e 9 Jan then I want my form text fields to be disabled for the next one month.So that user can only update once a month.

```
<input type="number" min="1" name="month" ng-model="year.month"
       class="form-control" required />
```

Comment: That has to be something managed by your server code if it's important.

Comment: The reason you want to do this on the server first is that browser code is easily bypassed (just use the JS console in the browser's JS console. (Or use a tool that can submit arbitrary HTTP requests like curl.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you use AngularJS i saw ng-model. I use pseudoCode, the the current month put in a variable and you compare in the service what the user choose. The compare append the bool result and put inside ng-disabled.

```js
 
    
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.isChange = function() {
      var now = new Date();
      monthNow = now.getMonth();
      if ((!$scope.year) || ($scope.year.month != monthNow)) {
        $scope.check = false;
      } else {
        $scope.check = true;
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="number" min="1" name="month" ng-model="year.month"
           class="form-control" required ng-disabled="check" ng-change="isChange()" ng-init="isChange()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: I think you use Angularjs. When you pass the month to the service and then you can check your month with the current month. By the check variable you can choose to disable the input tag. better now?

Comment: I put a fast way to do the same thing inside the controller.